# Trouble with dual boot ubuntu and kali linux

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

```
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.993342] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.993342] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.993351] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: id=00e5
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.993700] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: can't find dev
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.993723] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: id=00e5 ice of ID00e5
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.994078] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.994080] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] Receiver Error        
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.994080] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] Receiver Error 
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.994439] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: can't find device of ID00e5
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.994439] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: can't find device of ID00e5
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.994464] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: id=00e5
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.994816] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e5(Receiver ID)
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.994818] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
```

This is a piece of my messy black screen appearing after I boot into Grub, can someone help me to figure out this problem?

+hardware properties:

system: 64 bit;

CPU: Intel Core i5;

Graphics: NVIDIA Geforce 920M

Comment: Please post, at least, a readable image but always better text (ok, maybe not possible in this situation, so please, a readable image instead). Please [edit] accordingly and add the hardware specs.

Comment: I've edited, it looks pretty clear.

Comment: You may need to add `nomodeset` to which boot entry you're selecting until you install the Nvidia drivers.

Comment: can you explain for me?

Comment: At the Grub menu press 'e' to edit the entry and then add `nomodeset` in the same line where `quiet splash` is.

Comment: I try to add nomodeset at the end of this line then ctrl-x to boot.  At the first time, I can't login to my desktop. After that, I reboot, it didn't work, this error screen appears again

Comment: *I can't login to my desktop* is an entirely different problem.

Comment: I know. I've got rid of that problem but I still stuck with the error black screen showing up when I boot into ubuntu and Kali Linux

Comment: That's why you need `nomodeset` until you install the proprietary Nvidia drivers on both.

Comment: Do you mean that I must install Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu so I won't see error screen anymore once I boot into Ubuntu

Comment: Yes, on both actually.

Comment: I've done with ubuntu but i can't do that on kali linux because Kali can't connect to wifi

Comment: So you have to enable WiFi (drivers missing, probably) before other stuff. But Kali is off topic here anyway. You may ask at [unix.se].